# Получить значение из функции, привязанной к кнопке tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Пишу небольшую программу с GUI на Python+tkinter. Столкнулся с такой проблемой.
Есть функция

```
def open_file():
    path_to_file = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
```

И есть верхнее меню программы, в котором есть вкладка "Open...". К этой вкладке привязана функция open_file()

```
menu_file.add_command(label='Open...', command=open_file)
```

Естественно, когда я выбираю пункт открыть появляется диалоговое окно с выбором файла, но как мне полученный путь к файлу вернуть в основную программу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проще всего это сдеать используя класс, тогда строку, содержащую путь к файлу можно хранить как аттрибут экземпляра.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

class Window(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.value = None # сюда и будет записан путь к файлу

        menubar = tk.Menu(self)
        filemenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        filemenu.add_command(label='Open', command=self.open_file)
        menubar.add_cascade(label='File', menu=filemenu)
        self.config(menu=menubar)

    def open_file(self):
        path_to_file = askopenfilename()
        self.value = path_to_file


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Window()
    root.mainloop()
```